# How to make a hardcoded value in one cell move with a value in a parallel cell

Tags: excel

I have a sheet (sheet2) in Excel where the A column is a hardcoded sequence from 1-10000. The B column pulls a value (B) associated with the number in the A column (A) from another sheet (sheet1), where this number (A) expresses the current rank of (B) in (sheet1). As data is added to (sheet1), the rank of (B) in (sheet1) will change.

The problem is the following. In (sheet2), I need to assign a status (C) in the C Column for the (B) value. This (C) value is hardcoded, but the (B) value is a formula. If the rank associated with a particular (B) value in (sheet1) changes, the row of that (B) value in (sheet2) also changes.

How can I make sure that the hardcoded (C) value I assign to a (B) value in (sheet2) will change rows with that (B) value as the rank of (B) changes in (sheet1)?

For example, (B) value 'John' is ranked 1 in (sheet1), thus the formula pulls 'John' into cell B1. I write a comment in C1 "Out". If the rank of 'John' in (sheet1) changes to 2, the value in B1 is replaced, 'John' goes to B2, but the comment 'Out' I wrote in C1 stays in C1. How can I make that 'Out' travel with 'John'?

Comment: This does seem like you need to rethink your data setup, to be honest... seems like a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BigBen thanks for quick response. You're right. I've figured out a cleaner and simpler structure that works.

Comment: If this is solved.. you may deleted this question (to remove it from 'unanswered' list) /(^_^)